# Scraping Multiple Web Pages While Executing a Procedure

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is a web scraper that loops through each physician's profile from this [website](https://sportmedbc.com/practitioners?field_profile_first_name_value=&field_profile_last_name_value=&field_pract_profession_tid=All&city=&taxonomy_vocabulary_5_tid=All&page=0) and scrapes their information. The code runs without any errors, but I am trying to write a for loop that will allow me to scrape the first 5 pages of physician profiles. In my current code below, the output prints the information that is displayed on page 5 of the website, but I am struggling to figure out why it is not scraping the first 4 pages. This is my first time looping through a procedure, so I think something is going wrong once the code calls the webpage and then has to run the procedure. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from collections import ChainMap

pages=[]
for i in range(0,5):
    url = 'https://sportmedbc.com/practitioners?field_profile_first_name_value=&field_profile_last_name_value=&field_pract_profession_tid=All&city=&taxonomy_vocabulary_5_tid=All&page='+str(i)
    pages.append(url)

for item in pages:
    page=requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

def get_data(soup):
    default_data = {'name': 'n/a', 'clinic': 'n/a', 'profession': 'n/a', 'region': 'n/a', 'city': 'n/a'}

    for doctor in soup.select('.view-practitioners .practitioner'):
        doctor_data = {}

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text.strip():
            doctor_data['name'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text.strip():
            doctor_data['clinic'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text.strip():
            doctor_data['profession'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text.strip():
            doctor_data['region'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text.strip():
            doctor_data['city'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text

        yield ChainMap(doctor_data, default_data)

for doctor in get_data(soup):
    print('name:\t\t', doctor['name'])
    print('clinic:\t\t',doctor['clinic'])
    print('profession:\t',doctor['profession'])
    print('city:\t\t',doctor['city'])
    print('region:\t\t',doctor['region'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost ok, put the loop with `get_soup()` inside the first loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from collections import ChainMap

def get_data(soup):
    default_data = {'name': 'n/a', 'clinic': 'n/a', 'profession': 'n/a', 'region': 'n/a', 'city': 'n/a'}

    for doctor in soup.select('.view-practitioners .practitioner'):
        doctor_data = {}

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text.strip():
            doctor_data['name'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text.strip():
            doctor_data['clinic'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text.strip():
            doctor_data['profession'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text.strip():
            doctor_data['region'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text.strip():
            doctor_data['city'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text

        yield ChainMap(doctor_data, default_data)

url = 'https://sportmedbc.com/practitioners?field_profile_first_name_value=&field_profile_last_name_value=&field_pract_profession_tid=All&city=&taxonomy_vocabulary_5_tid=All&page=%s'

for i in range(5):
    page=requests.get(url % i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

    print('Page {}'.format(i + 1))
    print('#' * 80)
    for doctor in get_data(soup):
        print('name:\t\t', doctor['name'])
        print('clinic:\t\t',doctor['clinic'])
        print('profession:\t',doctor['profession'])
        print('city:\t\t',doctor['city'])
        print('region:\t\t',doctor['region'])
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Page 1
################################################################################
name:        Jaimie Ackerman
clinic:      n/a
profession:  n/a
city:        n/a
region:      n/a
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Marilyn Adams
clinic:      Fortius Sport & Health
profession:  Physiotherapist
city:        n/a
region:      Fraser River Delta
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Mahsa Ahmadi
clinic:      Wellpoint Acupuncture (Sports Medicine)
profession:  Acupuncturist
city:        Vancouver
region:      Vancouver & Sea to Sky
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Tracie Albisser
clinic:      Pacific Sport Northern BC, Tracie Albisser
profession:  Strength and Conditioning Specialist, Exercise Physiologist
city:        n/a
region:      Cariboo - North East
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Christine Alder
clinic:      n/a
profession:  n/a
city:        Vancouver
region:      Vancouver & Sea to Sky
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Steacy Alexander
clinic:      Go! Physiotherapy Sports and Wellness Centre
profession:  Physiotherapist
city:        Vancouver
region:      Vancouver & Sea to Sky
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Page Allison
clinic:      AET Clinic, .
profession:  Athletic Therapist
city:        Victoria
region:      Vancouver Island - Central Coast
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Dana Alumbaugh
clinic:      n/a
profession:  Podiatrist
city:        Squamish
region:      Vancouver & Sea to Sky
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Manouch Amel
clinic:      Mountainview Kinesiology Ltd.
profession:  Strength and Conditioning Specialist
city:        Anmore
region:      Vancouver & Sea to Sky
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Janet Ames
clinic:      Dr. Janet Ames
profession:  Physician
city:        Prince George
region:      Cariboo - North East
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Greg Anderson
clinic:      University of the Fraser Valley
profession:  Exercise Physiologist
city:        Mission
region:      Fraser Valley
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:        Sandi Anderson
clinic:      n/a
profession:  n/a
city:        Coquitlam
region:      Fraser Valley
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Page 2
################################################################################

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Andrej! I have one follow-up question regarding the order of the code. Should it be url, for loop calling soup, def get_data, then the print text at the bottom? When I include your edits in my code, I am still just scraping the 5th page, but this time it includes the text "page 1 ***********, page 2*********, etc. and I am not sure why this is. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @NateWalker I updated my answer and included full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in pages:
    page=requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')  # This sets soup to be the 5th page at the end of the loop.
```

Since soup is the 5th page as explained above, you get the result only for the 5th page.

Solution:

```
# Place this code at the bottom
for item in pages:
    page=requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    # Call the bottom loop here.
    for doctor in get_data(soup):
       print('name:\t\t', doctor['name'])
       print('clinic:\t\t',doctor['clinic'])
       print('profession:\t',doctor['profession'])
       print('city:\t\t',doctor['city'])
       print('region:\t\t',doctor['region'])
       print('-' * 80)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, anurag! Unfortunately, when I made this change, I was still getting only the 5th page in my output. Thanks again for the response!